# OpenGL, How to create a "bumpy Polygon"?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am unsure of how to describe what I'm after, so I drew a picture to help:

[image: OpenGL question]

My question, is it possible within OpenGL to create the illusion of those pixel looking bumps on a single polygon, without having to resort to using many polygons?  And if it is, what's the method?

Comment: I think this is bump mapping?  I may be wrong..

Comment: Did you draw that? Nice!

Comment: @nightcracker - Pfft!  It's not exactly a work of art, but thanks~

Comment: Looks like an Indiana Jones style riddle or trap!

Comment: @Desmond - I hope everyone has their fridge closeby

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think what your looking for is actually [Parallax mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_mapping) (Or Parallax Occlusion mapping).

Demos:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01owTezYC-w
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcAsJdo7dME&NR=1
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njKdLvmBl88

Parralax mapping basically works by using the height map to alter the texture UV coordinate being used.

The main disadvantage to parallax is that anything that appears to be 'outside' the polygon will be clipped (think of looking at an image on a 3D tv), so it's best for things indented in a surface rather than sticking out of it (although you can reduce this by making the polygon lager than the visible texture area). It's also fairly complex and would need to be combined with other shader techniques for a good effect.

Bump mapping works by using a texture for normal's, this makes the light's shading appear to be 3D however it does not change 3D data depending on the position of the viewer only the shading. Bump mapping would also be fairly useless for the OP's sample image since the surface is all the same angle just at different heights, bump mapping relies on the changes in the surfaces angles. You would have to slope the edges like [this](http://www.filterforge.com/filters/7582-normal.html).

Displacement mapping/tessellation uses a texture to generate more polygons rather than just being 1 polygon.

There's a video comparing all 3 [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnbYdkm1V4k)

EDIT: There is also [Relief mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief_mapping_(computer_graphics)), which is a similar to parallax. See [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_erYebogWUw&feature=related). There's a [comparison video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNnPFLb6YOg) too (it's a bit lowquality but relief looks like it gives better depth).

Answer (score 14):

I think what you're after is [bump mapping.](http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/simplebump/simplebump.html) The link goes to a simple tutorial.

Comment: Thank you!  ... I'm surprised it's actually called 'bump' mapping, aha.

Comment: I thought this was done with pixel shader (I still haven't moved on from OpenGL 1.2). Well I'll be damned!

Comment: you can do it in a shader too.

Comment: But you should consider that the effect of bump mapping may be noticeable only with moving light(s) or the surface moving in relation to the light(s). If you want bumping blocks to obstruct other blocks, bump mapping might not be an option.

Comment: @DesmondHume - Actually, having it obscure geometry was the effect I hoped to have.  I guess bump mapping isn't it then, dangit

Comment: Bump mapping is only designed to edit a vertex's normals, not its position.

Answer (score 13):

You may also be thinking of [displacement mapping](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/vertex_displacement_mapping.php).

Comment: It seems like that method increases the number of vectors and polygons needed though, quite dramatically too.

Comment: @Clairvoire displacement mapping is usually implemented by combining parallax mapping with OpenGL 4.0 or DX11 tessellation. This allows you to dynamically add detail in a performance friendly way.

Answer (score 6):

Of the techniques mentioned in other people's answers:

- Bump mapping is the easiest to achieve, but doesn't do any occlusion.
- Parallax mapping is probably the most complex to achieve, and doesn't work well in all cases.
- Displacement mapping requires high-end hardware and drivers, and creates additional geometry.
- Actually modeling the polygons is always an option.

It really depends on how close you expect the viewer to be and how prominent the bumps are. If you're flying down the Death Star trench, you'll need to model the bumps or use displacement mapping. If you're a few hundred meters up, bumpmapping should suffice.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  It's nice to see the techniques summed and compared against one another

Answer (score 3):

If you have DX11 class hardware then you could tessellate the polygon and then apply displacement mapping. See http://developer.nvidia.com/node/24. But then it gets a little complicated to get it running and develop something on top of it.

Comment: That looks interesting!  Though, Dx11 isn't something I can rely on, since a lot of my users will be lacking it.